# How to hide the output of a single Logback logger?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I use `logback` in the following case

```
package ninja.template;
public class TemplateEngineManagerImpl implements TemplateEngineManager {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TemplateEngineManagerImpl.class);

    ... 
    logger.info("Registered response template engines");
    ...
```

and I want to hide all the `INFO` output of this `TemplateEngineManagerImpl` class (or all the output - the class only logs at `INFO` level) but **this class only**.

Unfortunately, the following configuration doesn't work as I can still see "Registered response template engines" in my console output.

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT_TERSE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern> | %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="ninja.template.TemplateEngineManagerImpl" level="OFF"/>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT_TERSE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

> **note** I tried also the following without results

```
 <logger name="ninja.template.TemplateEngineManagerImpl" level="WARN"/>
```

and

```
 <logger name="ninja.template" level="WARN"/>
```

and

```
 <logger name="TemplateEngineManagerImpl" level="WARN"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided logback configuration works

```
<logger name="ninja.bodyparser.BodyParserEngineManagerImpl" level="WARN" additive="false"/>
```

The error I had that the string was logged in two different places.

So by displaying the full `logger` name with the following configuration:

```
<appender name="STDOUT_TERSE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<!-- encoders are assigned the type
     ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
<encoder>
  <pattern> | %logger | %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

I was able to copy and paste the string that should be used as the logger name!